# terminal not working properly in Qt

Tags: qt

I am having a Qt application which run on bootup of RPI. I am using system to run start the other application. Where I start the application from terminal(for testing purpose) the system command works properly but on boot up the system command doesn't works. I could not figure out whats wrong ......

Comment: You need to provide more information, remember we have zero information about your code, what it's trying to launch, how it is failing etc. "Doesn't work" is not enough information to debug anything.

Comment: If you have a GUI it needs the windows system to launch but maybe your application is launching before the window manager starts, so your application goes down.

Comment: I am using  "system(cmd.toLocal8Bit().data());". Let cmd I want to execute ....